# How to add a specific item's image as a background image in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

This one is frustrating me. I'm using paperclip for the images, and adding them to the model `offer` That's fine. My problem is adding them in as a background image on the index page for `offer` So my code looks like this:

```
<div class="product-image"></div>
<style>
.product-image {
     width: 50%;
     height: 200px;
     margin-left: 25%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-image: url(<%= image_tag offer.image %>);
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
}
</style>
```

When I inspect it on chrome, the code looks like this:

```
background-image: url(<img src="/system/offers/images/000/000/033/original/headphones.jpg?1468610654" alt="Headphones" />);
```

Anybody know a fix? Like I said, the images are working fine. If I simply put a line of code in as `<%= image_tag offer.image %>`, the image shows. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a image_tag helper that creates a html tag

You should use asset_url helper

```
asset_url('url for image in your asset folder')
```

if you choose to declare it on your css file (in your stylesheet assets) dont forget to rename it to scss.

Comment: It's not in my assets folder.... It's part of the model when I create a new `offer`

Comment: @rneves what do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot your post, the image is working.

Comment: if it's not on you asset, just use url('<%= @image.url %>')

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

If it isn't on your asset path, and `image_tag` was working, why not use just the path?

```
background-image: url(<%= offer.image %>);
```

Comment: No... Still gives me the same result. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your view

```
<div class="product-image" style="<%= show_user_bg %>"></div>
```

In your application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

 def show_user_bg
  if user_signed_in?
   "background:transparent url(offer.image}) no-repeat fixed left top;"
  else
  "background:transparent url('/images/default_bg.png') no-repeat fixed left top;"
  end
 end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
background-image: url('<%= offer.image %>');
```